# How do I increase the space in Filesystem Root partition?

Tags: partitioning

Ubuntu is my only OS. I recently downloaded many utilities for a lecture along with Visual Studio Code, and since then I have noticed unusual lag in my PC.

I cleared a lot of things using various tools like Bleach Bit and via terminal, yet, the lag still exists and opening applications is noticeably slower.

[image: Here is a screenshot]

[image: Here is the text version of the screenshot.]

I have space in my /home partition, I do not know if it is possible to reallocate sizes; is it practical?

I cannot use the swap partition as then I will have to unmount other partitions which includes home and root.

Edit: after applying the following commands, here is the screenshot of

[image]

Comment: Use `top` and `free` to diagnose the cause of lag. Use Disk Usage Analyzer or `du` to determine if you have unexpected space hogs on your Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Both / and /home are too small and nearly full. You should reinstall and allocate more space.

Comment: I could have used the answer you linked above, but he uses the swap partition, to delete swap partition I will have to unmount higher partition which is not possible.

Comment: Kartikeya, ever since fall of 2017, the Linux kernel has improved the swap file performance so that the only frequent need for a swap partition is if you have added Hibernation to your system. Once we have the results of `parted` we can discuss removing the swap partition without affecting performance. For details, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: I can afford to loose /dev/sda1 (105MB) , but /dev/sda2 has content that I require.

Comment: Yes, of course, could you tell me where to exactly copy and transfer the files. B) I was using elementary OS before it, I downloaded few important images and documents and therefore left sda6 as it is, while I was installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Partition changes are the quickest way to lose data by accident. Therefore i'd suggest making an external backup of what's in /dev/sda2. After the backup completes, verify what's on the backup matches the source. Then, backup _again_ to a different destination and verify _again_.  You can use an external drive and/or space in the cloud for this process. Then, you can boot from an Ubuntu Live USB and make partition moves and changes.   Oh, yes; what is in /dev/sda6 and why did you need to have it separate from /home?

Comment: PS: Please move the question regarding Visual Studio into a new question as it's a separate issue.

Comment: Is there no alternative to booting via Live USB? PS:Done.

Comment: What's on sda3 and sda6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Copy any last minute "few important images and documents" from sda6 to sda3 (as we'll delete sda6 (Elementary OS) later)**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **delete** /dev/sda6 partition (this will remove Elementary OS)
- **resize** the right side of <strike>/dev/sda8</strike> /dev/sda7 and add ~40G to <strike>/dev/sda8</strike> /dev/sda7

  - this leaves about 20G unallocated, which will get added to /dev/sda6 later
- **move** <strike>/dev/sda8</strike> /dev/sda7 partition all the way to the right
- **resize** the right side <strike>/dev/sda7</strike> /dev/sda6 all the way to the right

  - this adds about 20G to the /
- click the Apply icon
- `reboot` # reboot the computer
- `sudo update-grub` # update GRUB since the /dev/sda6 deletion

**Update #1:**

After deleting /dev/sda6, `gparted` has renumbered partitions, and then /dev/sda7 became /dev/sda6, and /dev/sda8 became /dev/sda7. Follow the same instructions, substituting the new partition numbers.

**Update #2:**

Boot to Ubuntu Live DVD/USB again. Start `terminal` and type:

- `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda6`
- `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda7`
- give me a new screenshot of `gparted`

**Update #3:**

`sudo umount /dev/sda2` # unmount this partition

`sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sda2` # try to fix ntfs partition

**Update #4:**

If you don't have `Users and Groups` application already installed, install it this way...

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools`

Show me the advanced settings for your account. Upload a screenshot to imgur.com and give me the URL.

Create a new **Administrative** user named "Administrator". Log out of your current user and test the login for Administrator account.

Upload a copy of `/etc/fstab` to paste.ubuntu.com and give me the URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105169/discussion-between-heynnema-and-kartikeya-srivastava).